# Swift and UIVisualEffectView with Vibracy: Clicked button doesn't get darker

Tags: swift, uivisualeffectview

Without a UIVisualEffectView with vibrancy clicked buttons do get a little bit darker. However this does not work, when vibrancy turned on. Any way to do this?

**Edit:**

It gets darker, when the UIButton only contains text. What I do is I use a background image for the UIButton. So I need the background image to get darker. I know this is possible by creating a second background image which is a bit darker. Then you could create an @IBAction, where the background gets changed when the user presses down the button. But the image doesn't get changed when clicking really fast on the button.

This happens for backgroundColor:

```
@IBAction func plusPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    plusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 119.0/255.0, green: 211.0/255.0, blue: 113.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

}

@IBAction func minusPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    minusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green:119.0/255.0, blue: 107.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?